# Operator & in haskell?

Tags: haskell, operator-keyword

How to check the second argument between an operation of true and false in haskell? E.g, `False && True` will only check the first argument and then will stop the operation. Is there something like `False & True` in Haskell to check both arguments?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Are we talking about generic Haskell, or GHC? You can use [bang patterns](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/bang-patterns.html) for this.

Comment: I need this because i am using report and in a function the second argument is never used because of this.

Comment: @P_Ferreira that would seem to imply that evaluating the second argument has side effects?

Comment: I think the asker is referring to a bitwise `&` like the one in javascript, which happens to act like a non-short-circuiting `&&` on boolean values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&&` in the prelude is implemented as

```
(&&) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
True  && x =  x
False && _ =  False
```

Which means in the case that the first argument is `False` the second
one is never evaluated. You could always implement your own version to have the behaviour that you want e.g.:

```
(.&&.) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
True  .&&. x =  x
False .&&. False =  False    
False .&&. True = False
```

In which the second second argument is evaluated in either case.

Comment: Wouldn't a smart compiler derive that the second argument can only be `True` or `False` and thus optimize this away?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No, because the second argument can also be `undefined`.  This definition implies the semantics `False .&&. undefined = undefined`, whereas the original implies `False && undefined = False`.  The compiler is not allowed to change this.

Answer (score 4):

There is no good reason why you'd want this, but if you insist...

```
import Control.Parallel (pseq)

(&&!) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
a &&! b = b `pseq` (a&&b)
```

Usually, [`seq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:seq) (which doesn't require any imports) will also suffice instead of [`pseq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel/docs/Control-Parallel.html#v:pseq), but only the latter actually guarantees that `b` will be evaluated.

Of course, the semantics of this function will be exactly the same as `&&` alone, it will just be slower in some cases.

Comment: Doesn't `seq` also force evaluation? I thought the difference was that `seq` forces evaluation before returning, and `pseq` forces evaluation before evaluating the second term.

Comment: You may be right. I usually think of ``b`seq`a`` as just a guarantee that the runtime does not leave `b` around as a non-WHNF thunk, without any reliable impact on what it _does_ leave around... but unless `b` can be optimised away entirely, this probably ensures also that it's WHNF'd before the result is given.

Comment: Technically `b \`seq\` a` just means that `b \`seq\` a` will be an infinite loop if `b` is. One optimization that is possible is `b \`seq\` a = a \`seq\` (b \`seq\` a)`, since this still satisfies that property.

Answer (score 2):

I was mislead by the OP's subject "Operator & in haskell?"

For those who are here looking for (&) in Haskell

**&** is a reverse application operator in Data.Function

`(&) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b`